# Trying to find the avearage value over Last pivots

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading

I am looking to find the average of last N pivots based on a length. For example, Finding the average of last N pivot highs and last N pivot lows using Pine Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the average of a serie, you can use ta.sma(serie_name, N) with N the number of data used to calculate the average.
You should try this :

```
//@version=5
indicator(Pivot average", overlay=true)
N = 10

leftBars = input(2)
rightBars=input(2)
ph = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
average = ta.sma(ph, N)
plot(average)
```